# xcode and java code

Tags: java, objective-c, xcode, xcode4, mahout

I want to ask if it is possible to add "Java" code in my Xcode?

since I want to import "Mahout apache" for recommendation algorithm which is written in Java.

or if you have any other idea which help me to get related "object"

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this document ?

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/02-JavaDevTools/JavaDevTools.html

Keep in mind that Java is not a first class citizen of Xcode anymore.

This is from a maling list

> 

Mike Swingler
Fri Mar 11 16:00:50 2011
On Mar 10, 2011, at 10:37 AM, Jeremy E. Denton wrote:

> Sorry, I may have missed it because I only look at it every once in a while 
>   but did XCode stop supporting Java? Or do I just have to download some sort 
>   of extension?

Xcode is an Objective-C IDE first, and it's support for Java in it's build 
system is equivalent to calling any other command line tool. The Java team at 
Apple uses Xcode for native development of JNI libraries and light Java 
editing, but to be most productive you will want to use a real Java IDE like 
Eclipse, IDEA, or NetBeans.

We have also transitioned the JNI Library template in Xcode 3.x to sample code, 
which shows how to build a bundled Java Mac app with a JNI library:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MyFirstJNIProject

Regards,
Mike Swingler
Java Engineering
Apple Inc.

---

Do not post admin requests to the list. They will be ignored.
Java-dev mailing list      ([EMAIL PROTECTED])
Help/Unsubscribe/Update your Subscription:

Comment: I didn't understand what "Keep in mind that Java is not a first class citizen of Xcode anymore" can you explain it ! 
do you mean that it's not good as it is ?

Comment: What about "Mahout" are you well known about it ? 
or if you have any algorithm that has same idea of Mahout recommender?

Comment: Edited my answer. I hope it explains first class citizen